# Nginx/proxy not working properly

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, command-line-interface

I recently uninstalled apache2 for Nginx
I'm trying to listen on 88, 808 and 888 for my sites and redirect different subdomains for each (and another domain to another server).
the problem is that Nginx is giving bad gateway for all proxied requests and timeout for the direct ip access.

**proxy conf :**  --> otherdomain.fr = eror 502 bad gateway

```
# HTTP
server {
    # Listen on ipv4
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    server_name  ~.*.otherdomain.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.1.17";
    }
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name nextcloud.domain.me;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:888";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.me;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:808";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**ex for port 88:** --> ip:88 = timeout

(obviously, it is enabled and the nginx user have access to the files)

```
server {
    # Listen on ipv4
    listen 88;
  
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/tests;
    }

}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I cant find out what, if you could give me a hand it would be incredible.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT :

**netstat -tulpen | grep -E '8.?8'**

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10028         0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN      0          28186      1929/master tcp        0      0
> 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          91603      8801/nginx: master tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12340
> 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25868      734/dovecot tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN      0          19881      497/cupsd tcp        0      0
> 0.0.0.0:88              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          75033      8801/nginx: master tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:888
> 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          75032      8801/nginx: master tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN      0          75030      8801/nginx: master tcp        0
> 0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0
> 28182      1929/master udp6       0      0 :::32885
> :::*                                113        21172
> 482/avahi-daemon: r"""

Comment: What's the reason to differentiate the ports and then proxying them? What's the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep -E '8.?8?'`` ? Do you have `listen` directives for all of these ports?

Comment: 1./ I'm proxying and differentiate the ports because I use a different server for each one (808 is a cherrypy serv actually not running, otherdomain.fr is another machine (apache2), 888 is nextcloud with this instance of nginx (and php8.0) and I only use 88 for testing purposes so I don't use a subdomain for it)

2./ see EDIT

3./ yes I do

Comment: EDIT : I could remove the port for nextcloud and maybe port 88

Comment: nginx requires either a location, an server name or an ip in the servername. else it will imho not serve the contents as it does not know whatever to do with it., moreover for what reason do you uae `~.*.` in servername?

Comment: What is the content of nginx `error.log`?

Comment: @djdomi the regex is made to redirect every subdomain of otherdomain.fr to this ip

Comment: @TeroKilkanen 
For 3 requests :
otherdomain.fr
domain.me:88
nextcloud.domain.me

I get : 
`2021/11/05 10:05:52 [error] 22452#22452: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.70.90.59, server: ~.*.otherdomain.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream$
2021/11/05 10:05:55 [error] 22452#22452: *3 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.70.162.73, server: ~.*.otherdomain.fr, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.$`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes around the destination URL of `proxy_pass`.

Main problem is the `server_name ~.*.otherdomain.fr` and the fact that you are using `proxy_set_header Host $host`.

In this case it seems your regular expression for `server_name` is invalid and it is taken as a string. That string appears then in `$host` variable.

You should try

```
server_name *.otherdomain.fr;
```

instead. If that doesn't work, use

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Which passes the HTTP Host header onward instead of contents of `$host` variable.

Comment: i was guessing correctly that regrx works but is conflict with the rest ;) thabks fir the clarification of my thoughts